# How to specify the EJB bean name in the JNDI tree in JEE7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, java-ee-6

I'm not sure if this is a generic JEE6 question or if it is a Wildfly 10/JBoss7 EAP implementation specific question.

I'm trying to specify/override the default beanName used in my EJB JNDI mapping to something more meaningful to me.

For example:

LoginManagerBean:

```
@Stateless
public class LoginManagerBean extends BaseManagerBean implements LoginManager {
....
}
```

LoginManager:

```
@Local
public interface LoginManager{
....
}
```

In this context, WF10 will automatically create a JNDI mapping for this EJB as:

```
ejb:myApp/myJar/LoginManagerBean!LoginManager
```

In the Wildfly 10 documentation for [EJB naming conventions](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI), it says
For stateless beans:

> ```
> ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>
> ```
>
> .... ....
>
> bean-name : This is the name of the bean for which you are doing the
>   lookup. The bean name is typically the unqualified classname of the
>   bean implementation class, but can be overriden through either
>   ejb-jar.xml or via annotations. The bean name part cannot be an empty
>   string in the JNDI name.

However, I cannot seem to find which annotation to use to specify the bean name in an annotation.  If I read the docs for [@EJB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html) it states that the `beanName` parameter is:

> The ejb-name of the Enterprise Java Bean to which this reference is mapped

So from the docs, it does not seem that the beanName is the right parameter to use.

So how can I rename my EJB beanName in the mapping to something of my choice?  For instance, what annotation can I use to make the mapping read:

```
ejb:myApp/myJar/MyReallyCoolName!LoginManager
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using JBossEAP 7/WildFly 10.x then this is JavaEE 7, although the same answer applies to Java EE 6.

You only appear to be using Local interfaces, so none of the instructions that you linked apply because they are only for **remote EJB clients**. Therefore these statements:

> In this context, WF10 will automatically create a JNDI mapping for this EJB as:
>
> ```
> ejb:myApp/myJar/LoginManagerBean!LoginManager
> ```

are completely incorrect.

When you deploy your application all of the JNDI names are logged in the server console:

```
java:global/serverapp/LoginManagerBean!com.stackoverflow.p43282192.LoginManager
java:app/serverapp/LoginManagerBean!com.stackoverflow.p43282192.LoginManager
java:module/LoginManagerBean!com.stackoverflow.p43282192.LoginManager
java:global/serverapp/LoginManagerBean
java:app/serverapp/LoginManagerBean
java:module/LoginManagerBean
```

Most of the time you should not care about the JNDI names because in general each EJB is unique and the server will find the right implementation:

```
public class LoginClient {

    @EJB
    private LoginManager loginManager;

    ...
```

}

If you want to use JNDI lookups and you want to create more work for yourself then you can specify the bean name:

```
@Stateless(name="Foo")
public class LoginManagerBean implements LoginManager {

   ...
```

which yields:

```
java:global/serverapp/Foo!com.stackoverflow.p43282192.LoginManager
java:app/serverapp/Foo!com.stackoverflow.p43282192.LoginManager
java:module/Foo!com.stackoverflow.p43282192.LoginManager
java:global/serverapp/Foo
java:app/serverapp/Foo
java:module/Foo
```

and you can look these up if you must:

```
LoginManager loginManager = (LoginManager)(new InitialContext().lookup("java:app/serverapp/Foo"));
```

or using injection:

```
     @EJB(beanName="Foo")
     private LoginManager loginManager;
```

BTW, I'm just deploying the sample EJB jar here (serverapp.jar). Some of the names have an additional path element if you're using an EAR file.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That was exactly the piece I was missing.  I didn't realize there was a name parameter in the `@Stateless` annotation!  My issue is revolving around a legacy JEE5 application running in JB4 that is being migrated to WF10, so currently all beans are being loaded via JNDI lookups.  So the first step is to make the old lookups work properly (by overriding the default bean name), and once that is working, then migrating to proper DI using `@EJB` or `@Inject` annotations.

Comment: Is your legacy app using `java:comp/env/...` style names or global JNDI names for JNDI lookups? The former is easy to port and the latter more difficult.

Comment: Quite frankly - I'm not entirely sure.  I took a quick look at the code and it is specifying the JNDI name via a Jboss LocalBinding annotation, and the lookup is just retrieving the bean from an InitialContext lookup based on the JNDI name.  I'm actually not entirely sure if that uses the global namespace or the comp/env namespace.  Right now, my lookup is fairly simple: `MyEjb ejb = (MyEjb) new InitialContext().lookup("myReallyCoolBeanName")`.  Any ideas which namespace that uses?

Comment: That would be a global name which is essentially non-portable.

Comment: @SteveC sadly JNDI lookup was the *only* solution that worked for me in Wildfly 10+JEE7 WAR from a ServletFilter (Apache Shiro), which is even `@ApplicationScoped` so `@EJB` injection should work, but none of the variations I tried (and I tried many!) worked...